# rosmaster zombie

Tags: ros, rosnode, master, rosmaster, roscore

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I know [zombie node can exist](http://answers.ros.org/question/9521/rosnode-zombies/) but is zombie master possible too?

With the following step, I keep getting `rosgraph.masterapi.Master` instance even after I stop `master`, which is not my intent. What's wrong?

1. Run `master` (eg. by `roscore`)
2. Run `$ rosrun turtlesim turtlesim_node`
3. Run the python script I cite at the bottom. It keeps printing the instance info.
4. Stop `master`. Surprisingly, print continues with the same content.

After 3, both 2 processes with the names `roscore` and `rosmaster --core` don't seem to be running. Stopping `turtlesim` when `master` is already stopped doesn't change anything. I suspect rosmaster could be sustaining even after it's shut down?

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import time

import rosgraph
import rosnode


def prv_master_rosnode():
    master = rosgraph.Master('/rosnode')
    print 'master={}'.format(master)
    rosn = rosnode.get_api_uri(master, '/turtlesim')
    print 'rosnode obj={}'.format(rosn)


def prv_master_rosnode_iterate():
    while True:
        prv_master_rosnode()
        time.sleep(1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    prv_master_rosnode_iterate()
```

Printed:

```
master=<rosgraph.masterapi.Master object at 0x7fc400553fd0>
rosnode obj=http://ramenrobot:52240/
master=<rosgraph.masterapi.Master object at 0x7fc400553fd0>
rosnode obj=http://ramenrobot:52240/
master=<rosgraph.masterapi.Master object at 0x7fc400553fd0>
rosnode obj=http://ramenrobot:52240/
: (never changes, never stops)
```

- ros-groovy-rosnode 1.9.44-0quantal-20130326-0855-+0000
- ros-groovy-rosgraph 1.9.44-0quantal-20130325-0834-+0000

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/61634/rosmaster-zombie/) by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10937 on 2013-04-26

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think something else is happening here.
If you verified the processes do not run anymore (e.g. look via `ps`), they cannot give a reply because the binary just does not exist. The problem just linked is based on the fact that the master doesn't unregister nodes, so if the binary is gone, that can't be it.

I'd probably look into what the python API gives you or specifies, i.e. why do you still get the same replies. If it caches (and should) that's desired behavior. If it should contact the master to get that kind of info, something seems buggy.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2013-04-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0